# Is there a Windows equivalent for the UNIX ldd command?

Tags: windows, powershell, dll, command-line, ldd

I have a list of DLLs and I would like to know the versions of all other DLLs, used by those files. In UNIX this is very simple:

```
ldd *.dll
```

But in Windows this does not work (I tried using my Ubuntu WSL).

Does anybody know a commandline command for this? (Powershell is good, too)

Comment: PSA: For security reasons, never run `ldd` on an unknown/untrusted file, since it actually executes the specified file.

Comment: nothing exactly the same, but in PowerShell there are several things you can do to get that info: `(Get-Item C:\my.dll).VersionInfo.FileVersion`, or `(Get-Command C:\my.dll).Version`, even using `[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo("C:\my.dll")`. To do this for a listing of all in the current directory just use the pipeline to select the info: `gci *.dll | %{$_.VersionInfo}` add `-Recurse` for recursive listings, and same applies to the others methods mentioned above.

Comment: @Abraham that's useful for getting versions of the DLLs in his list.  You seem not to have attempted the "other DLLs, used by those [DLLs in the list]"

Comment: @BenVoigt, ahh, me and my selective reading lol. Not too sure how to go about that. Only know how to do it once it's already loaded: `(ps "notepad").modules`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dumpbin.exe /imports` will list the immediate static load dependencies, but not attempt to resolve them (which implies no version numbers nor transitive dependencies)

`depends.exe` will resolve dependencies (including dynamic load ones if you run in "profiler" mode which supports a variety of different methods for hooking `LoadLibrary(Ex)` and `GetProcAddress`) but is not a command-line tool.  For each dependency it lists the path and version number, along with a lot of other information such as link date and required OS version -- you should be able to save this list to a file for command-line processing.

Neither of these is included in the OS distribution, you'll need a Windows SDK tools package.

Answer (score 3):

If you install [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/), it comes with an `ldd` which works on native Windows `.exe` and `.dll` files.